# is prism a pure mvvm platform?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

i'm working with WPF for quite some time now.
the platform i used is MVVM Light.
and i must say i don't add a single line of code in the code-behind files.

lately i dived into Prism, and i see many many examples where code-behind (such as 
data context, or property change events) is a matter of course.

is Prism considered as pure mvvm platform ?

although the implementation of IoC this still break the rules of mvvm:

```
[Import]
public MainViewModel ViewModel
{
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Prism` is a facilitator of `MVVM`, not a platform.   It's the role of the developer to follow the principals of `MVVM`.  I suspect there are many Prism apps that don't follow the principals of `MVVM`.  I've even worked on one.

Answer (score 1):

No, Prism is a [**Composite Application**](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) platform (if *platform* is the correct name, probably *Library* is better).

The fact that you want to use MVVM has nothing to do with Prism itself. You *can* use MVVM and Prism together.

Answer (score 1):

Prism is a framework to build complex, composite applications which base on recommended practicies from Microsoft. MVVM is one those practice, the other one is modularity of application. That's why you can see an applicaiton which uses Prism but not follows MVVM - it just has modularity structure and uses Prism to lazy module downloading, declarative module including etc.

But Prism is excellent MVVM framework itself. It provides implementation of base MVVM patterns:

- base view model - NotifyProertyChangesBase
- command - DelegateCommand
- notification between view models (for composite applications) -
  EventAggregator
- abstraction over user notification which can be used
  on view model level - Notification
- respects DI principle for unit
  testing of view models
- extentended ability to map view model to view - Regions

Prism as MVVM framework is heavy for small application, but it's very powerfull and extendable and I saw good composite MVVM-designed applications which was created using Prism.